# Condensing lots of Button Click Events

Tags: c#, refactoring

I have 40 buttons that all do something slightly different when clicked, I would like to condense this down if I can. I also want to say, if one of the buttons is clicked, create a timestamp which can be accessed by the class.

Here is the code for 2 out of 40 of the buttons:

```
private void Btn1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
   {
       CheckBox CheckBox = (this.FindName(string.Format("Check{0}", i)) as CheckBox);

       if (CheckBox != null)
       {
          CheckBox.IsChecked = true;
       }
    }
}

private void BtnDisable1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
  {
    CheckBox CheckBox1 = (this.FindName(string.Format("Check_D{0}", i)) as CheckBox);

    if (CheckBox1 != null)
    {
       CheckBox1.IsChecked = false;
    }
  }
}
```

I think one way of doing it is putting it in an array and whenever one of the 40 buttons are clicked it looks in the array on what to do next? I'm not really sure, thank you!

Comment: please avoid putting extra spaces between every line. they just make code harder to read. I just edited your question and removed them.(i cant imagine what it would look like with 40 buttons!). anyway you can use methods for this purpose and pass them functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make this simple using one method.

Answer is updated based on [this](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96253/discussion-between-tom-pitts-and-m-kazem-akhgary) discussion

```
private void DoWork(int checkboxGroup, bool enable)
{
    int start = checkboxGroup * 4;
    for (int i = start; i < start + 4; i++)
    {
        CheckBox CheckBox = this.FindName("CheckBox" + i) as CheckBox;

        if (CheckBox != null)
        {
            CheckBox.IsChecked = enable;
        }
    }
}

private void Btn1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DoWork(1 , true);
}
private void BtnDisable1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DoWork(1 , false);
}
```

Because there are 40 methods like this you can use Expression bodied methods. You must have C#6 to use this feature.

```
private void Btn1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) => DoWork(1 , true);
private void BtnDisable1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) => DoWork(1 , false);

private void Btn2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) => DoWork(2, true);
private void BtnDisable2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) => DoWork(2, false);

// and so on
```

Comment: But BtnDisable1 uses a different string checker, it checks for "Check_D".

Comment: Oh. didnt see. wait i fix it.

Comment: @TomPitts see the edit. i suggest you show your exact case (if you didnt already). because using delegates are tricky some times. how ever you can read tutorials about them. they are available in internet. for example http://www.dotnetperls.com/action and also http://www.dotnetperls.com/func

Comment: Problem I'm having is that when you click the button it should enable or disable more than one check box. Each checkbox is called: CheckBox, CheckBox1, CheckBox2 and so on. 4 checkboxes to each button.

Comment: I edited your code, as you can see, I want to enable checkboxes 1-4 by searching for all checkboxes called: CheckBox(i) where i is in the for loop. I then want to either enable or disable them dependent on if an enable button or a disable button is clicked.

Comment: @TomPitts aha. i got what you mean. you dont need delegate. sorry my mistake. you just need a single method.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96253/discussion-between-tom-pitts-and-m-kazem-akhgary).